# disk space error during upgrading ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bash, upgrade, root

I was upgrading ubuntu to 16.04 version. And maybe during installation of ubuntu the disk space allocated to ubuntu was less on my laptop. Thus the upgrade was complete. Now during boot it shows the error:

-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document : No space left on device.

I tried to mount windows drive here but for I need to be root login 
which I am not able to login. 
When I try to login root with command 
sudo su root or su 
Error message says :
Cannot execute /bin/tcsh

Please tell what should I do??

Comment: was not complete * (sorry typing error)

Comment: You might want to just boot a live-USB and back up your `/home` (if it's on the same partition as the OS) and re-install Ubuntu.  Fixing your current install is probably possible, but may take a lot of time.  (And depending on how well you understand `dpkg` / `debsums` / etc., may require expertise you don't have to make sure all Uubntu files are correct when you're done).

Comment: Or maybe Ubuntu's upgrade system does make it possible to revert back to a working system so you can free up some space before trying again to upgrade.  I don't know of one, but I'm not prepared to post an answer claiming it's impossible.

Comment: how do I back up home to USB